HuggingFace model loaded from the disk generates gibberish
I trained a LongT5 model using Huggingface's tooling.
When I use the trained model directly after training the inference works as expected, I get good quality output, as expected from the training metrics. However if I save the model and load it from the disk, the output is gibberish. I can't figure out why.
Code producing good output:
text = dataset['test'][0]['from']
inputs = tokenizer(text, return_tensors="pt").input_ids
inputs = inputs.to('cuda:0')

model.eval()

with torch.no_grad():
    model.to('cuda:0')
    model.generation_config = generation_config
    outputs = model.generate(inputs)

translation = tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

# Prints correct output
print(translation)

How I save the model:
trainer.save_model(os.path.join(model_output_dir, "final"))
tokenizer.save_pretrained(os.path.join(model_output_dir, "final"))

How I load the model:
model = LongT5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(os.path.join(model_output_dir, "final"))
model.to('cuda:0')
model.generation_config = generation_config

outputs = model.generate(inputs)

translation = tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True)

# Prints random garbage, like:
# pamper verre195188 albums188 albums188188 albums188 albums188 albums188 albums; unterschiedlich188 albums188 albums188 albums ...

print(translation)

In both cases, the tokenizer is the instance that already exists in memory during the training, but it doesn't make a difference whether I load it from the disk or not -- same result.
The generation_config variable looks like this and it's also set in the training arguments:
generation_config = GenerationConfig.from_model_config(model.config)
generation_config._from_model_config = False
generation_config.max_new_tokens = 512

It makes no difference whether it's set in the inference code or not, I still get gibberish.

Add a minimally reproducible code example what we can run to reproduce this

@seralouk here is all the code you need to reproduce it: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/g52tptuwmvrya0h0d0ld5/AFBWJNJSgy_jdejSOTsEpYw?rlkey=x92b8d5bqhfa034ldgt1jd9tg&dl=0

So the problem seems to be that the encoder.embed_tokens.weight and decoder.embed_tokens.weight state are not saved when the model is saved and every time it's loaded it gets reinitialized to random values. Not sure why that happens.

So, it turns out some strange bug in the current stable version of safetensors. It doesn't save the encoder.embed_tokens.weight and decoder.embed_tokens.weight state, so when the model is loaded again, these layers are initialized with random numbers.
There are two workarounds:

Use the latest version of safetensors where this seems to be fixed:

!pip install -U git+https://github.com/huggingface/safetensors.git


Don't use safetensors to save your model at all. You can set save_safetensors=False in the training arguments, so that HF will use pickle to save your model instead of safetensors.

